# What is the equivalent of millis() in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to create a PID controller in C++ based on an Arduino code. The original code uses the function millis() to retrieve the number of milliseconds the arduino has ran. I was curious if there was an equivalent in C++.

Comment: So, in more general terms you want to measure time, try looking for that on google first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do all you need using the std::chrono library (since c++11)

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream> 
int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    do_sth();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "do_sth() "
                  << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
                  << "ms.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple wrapper class for the chrono library to be easy to use for getting the elapsed time:

```cpp
#include <chrono>

class Stopwatch {
private:
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start_time;

public:
    void start() {
        start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

    long elapsed_time() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start_time).count();
    }
};
```

So when you have to measure time, you can use like this:

```cpp
Stopwatch s;
s.start();

// Do some stuff here...

cout << "Elapsed time in millis: " << s.elapsed_time();
```